# Why is convex conjugate defined on functions taking values on extended real line?

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis, definition

Recall a definition of convex conjugate (taken from [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_conjugate#Definition)):

> Let $X$ be a real topological vector space, and let $X^*$ be the dual space to $X.$
>   Denote the dual pairing by 
>   $$\langle \cdot,\cdot \rangle :X^*\times X\to\mathbb{R}.$$
>   For a function $f:X\to \mathbb{R}\cup \{-\infty,\infty\}$
>   taking values on the extended real number line, the **convex conjugate**
>   $$f^*:X^*\to\mathbb{R}\cup\{-\infty,\infty\}$$
>   is defined in terms of the supremum by 
>   $$f^*(x^*) =\sup\{ \langle x^*,x \rangle -f(x)| x\in X \},$$
>   or, equivalently, in terms of the infimum by
>   $$f^*(x^*) =-\inf\{ f(x) -\langle x^*,x \rangle | x\in X \},$$

Do we really need codomain of $f$ to be $\mathbb{R}\cup\{-\infty,\infty\}?$
Would anything go wrong if codomain of $f$ is just $\mathbb{R}?$

Comment: Since $\mathbb R$ is a subset of $\mathbb R\cup\left\{-\infty,\infty\right\}$, you can of course take any $f\colon X\to\mathbb R$ as well. However, $f^*$ might still take the value $+\infty$ for some $x^*\in X^*$.

Comment: In convex analysis, it's convenient to allow functions to take on extended real values. For example, even if the convex functions $f_i$ are finite everywhere, the function $f(x) = \sup_i f_i(x)$ might take on the value $+\infty$ for some values of $x$. Also, in convex optimization it's often useful to enforce hard constraints using convex indicator functions. A constraint $x \in C$ in an optimization problem can be enforced by including the term $I_C(x)$ in the objective function (where $I_C(x) = 0$ if $x \in C$ and $I_C(x) = \infty$ otherwise).

Comment: @littleO It seems that you are answering why the convex conjugate can take values on extended real line. But I am curious whether the original function $f$ must take value on extended real line..

Comment: Here's one observation: One of the most important facts about the conjugate is that if $f$ is a closed convex function then $(f^*)^* = f$. In order to state this fact, we must be able to take the conjugate of $f^*$, which might not be finite everywhere.

Comment: @littleO I see. I have a clearer picture now. Thanks.