# What does it mean when we say '$f$ is a function taking values on $\mathbb{R}$ $\cup$ {$-\infty, \infty$}'?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation, terminology

I was recently reading [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3026887/why-is-convex-conjugate-defined-on-functions-taking-values-on-extended-real-line) and noticed some terminology I am not familiar with. The title of the post is "*Why is convex conjugate defined on functions taking values on extended real line?*"

What does it mean when we say 'a function $f : X \to \mathbb{R}$ $\cup$ {$-\infty, \infty$} **taking values on the extended real line**'? Does saying "$f$ is a function taking values on the extended real line (or any set, in a general sense)" mean the function values are elements of $\mathbb{R}$ $\cup$ {$-\infty, \infty$}?

Comment: Yes, exactly that

Comment: It means the output of the function could be any real number, or $\pm \infty$. This output space is often referred to as the 'extended real line'.

Comment: Cf. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_real_number_line)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is just as you say.  A function goes from one set to another.  The text is defining what set the range is contained in, which is just as you think $\Bbb R \cup \{-\infty,\infty\}$

The motivation is that there are sets of reals that do not have a supremum in the reals.  The set of natural numbers, for example, does not.  If we add $\pm \infty$ to the reals, we have a compact set and every subset that is bounded above has a least upper bound.  For the naturals, it is $+\infty$.

Comment: Thank you @Ross Millikan for clearing up my question, as well as adding a little extra! Much appreciated.

Comment: Another motivation is that it can simplify notation. For example, in convex analysis one may wish to define a function such as $f(x) = { 1\over x}$ on $C=(0,\infty)$. Instead of lugging around $f,C$ one simply defines $f(x) = +\infty$ for $x \notin C$. Hence the effective domain is part of the data of $f$. This simple device simplifies the statement of many results.